# How to share module using Stack

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

My project structure:

```
MyProj
    app
    benchmarks
        Investigate.hs
    src
    test
        Example1.hs -- defines module Example1
```

My current `package.yaml` (simplified):

```
name: proj

dependencies:
- base >= 4.7 && < 5

library:
  source-dirs: src

executables:
  proj-exe:
    main: Main.hs
    source-dirs: app
    dependencies: proj

tests:
  proj-test:
    main: Spec.hs
    source-dirs: test
    dependencies: proj

benchmarks:
  investigate:
    main: benchmarks/Investigate.hs
    dependencies: proj
```

I want to import a module (say `Example1` that lives under *test*, and use it in `Investigate.hs` under *benchmarks*. I am using `stack`, so how exactly do I configure my `package.yaml`?

Answer (score 1):

The obvious thing to do is to add an additional internal (private) library block to your package and put the shared code there, where it can be added to the `dependencies` of both your tests and benchmarks.

Or you could make a separate folder of utility code for tests and benchmarks, and then include that folder in the `source-dirs` list of both; there's nothing stopping a single folder being referenced in the `source-dirs` of multiple components (although the downside is any files within will be compiled separately for each component, not compiled once and then shared).

I don't use stack, so I don't know precisely how either of these things manifest in their package.yaml syntax, but they are features of cabal-the-library, so I'm pretty sure stack should support them.

Answer (score 0):

Notice that when you use `dependecies: proj` you are saying "This executable depends on the *library* proj"; and library *proj* lives within `src` as you specified. If you want to use a function in benchmarks and test suites, you should add it to a module within the library source directories: `src`. Below your `package.yaml` with comments. I also included a wrong line at the end so it is clear why you must put the functionality under `src`.

```yaml
name: proj  # This is the name of the library. Generally one library per project. You can use you `stack.yaml` to define more.

dependencies:
- base >= 4.7 && < 5

library:  # Here is where the library functionality lives.
  source-dirs: src  

executables:           # This is your executable
  proj-exe:
    main: Main.hs
    source-dirs: app   # Living under app directory
    dependencies: proj # Which depends on the library. Which lives under src

tests:                 # This is your test suit
  proj-test:
    main: Spec.hs
    source-dirs: test  # Living under test directory
    dependencies: proj # Which depends on the library. Which lives under src

benchmarks:    # This is your benchmark. If you want to use a function living in 
  investigate: # the test folder, you would add it to the dependencies... but that's not allowed!!
    main: benchmarks/Investigate.hs
    dependencies: 
      - proj      # dependency on the library proj living under src
      - proj-test # This isn't allow because proj-test is not a library, is a test suite
```

Comment: Yes, this is actually what I currently have, and it "works". What I don't like about it is that a module living under source -- namely the one I want to share with test and bench -- is **not** part of the pkg that I want to share with the world. It is private and is only meant for internal purposes.

Comment: ah ok, you can make internal libraries, but thats supported with cabal only: https://cabal.readthedocs.io/en/3.4/cabal-package.html#sublibs. AFAIK, `stack` doesn't support this. A common approach is to put internal functions within a module called `Internal`, but this isn't encapsulation, but convention.

Comment: As an example of `Internal` module you can check [bytestring](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/bytestring-0.11.3.1) documentation